# Require_once PHP Error

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I've been programming in PHP for several years now and *never* encountered this error before.

Here's my **widget.php** file:

```
require_once('fruit.php');
echo "I am compiling just fine!!!";
```

And my **fruit.php** file:

```
$bVar = true;
```

When these two files look like this ^ then everything compiles with no errors and I get the "*I am compiling just fine!!!*" success message.

Now, the minute I move the **fruit.php** file one directory level up, and change my **widget.php** file to reflect the directory restructuring:

```
require_once('../fruit.php');
echo "I am compiling just fine!!!";
```

Now all the sudden, I get PHP warnings & fatal errors:

```
Warning: require_once(../fruit.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /webroot/app/widget.php on line 1

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../fruit.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in /webroot/app/widget.php on line 1
```

In all my years working with PHP, I've **never** seen require_once() fail like this before. Any ideas?!?!

Comment: The only thing I can immediately think of, have you checked the webserver user's permissions for the parent folder?  You may want to confirm the operating system, webserver, etc.  I can see that being relevant in this case.

Comment: +1 for Jeff ... does the web server "user" have access to the parent directory.

Comment: is there something funky with the permissions?

Comment: Is `fruit.php` still within the webroot of your server?

Comment: @Jeff Parker - no that never crossed my mind; I would have to call up the host and ask. Would this be a variable in Apache or PHP? Which file and variable name? And thanks!

Comment: You can require() or include() things outside your webroot.

Comment: Oh, and heres the other thing: the behavior is the *exact same* if I keep fruit.php in the same directory as widget.php but just change require_once('fruit.php'); to require_once('./fruit.php');... so I don't think its a directory permissions issue...

Comment: @marchaos - Yes both of these files are actually buried pretty deep within my webroot

Comment: I don't think so; please see my last comment under the original post

Comment: A small tip. Thy shalt first always check the file permissions when thee finds "failed opening xx file error". Most probably its a permission error. Can the user, mostly it will be Apache if its for web, run the file `fruit.php`?

Comment: @Kumar - Yes fruit.php is something I wrote and has no problem executing/compiling as long as its in the same directory as widget.php

Comment: Have you tried using `__DIR__` to require files using an absolute path  instead of a relative path ?

Comment: @kim, you didn't get my point. Are you running `widget.php` through Apache or is it a CLI script? You must understand the way PHP scripts run, on CLI/command line PHP runs a PHP script but when you use the same script for a webpage a webserver executes that script. That webserver exists as a user on *nix systems, for e.g. on my machine its `www-data`. Moreover can you do a `ls -al fruit.php` on shell and check what are the permissions set on this script?

Comment: So, I am trying to use `__DIR__` and it won't even evaluate. The following code: die(`__DIR__`); literally prints "`__DIR__`" to the screen. Does this provide any clues? Also, @Kumar, this is through Apache (the PHP script is serving as a web page); hopefully that helps.

Comment: `__DIR__` failing? What kind of set up you are using? is it on Windows or Linux? I am not sure about Windows as am on Debian 24x7

Answer (score 15):

Maybe you are in the wrong work directory. Its a bad idea to rely on it (except you explictly want to access it) anyway. Use

```
require __DIR__ . '/../fruit.php';
```

or with pre-5.3

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../fruit.php';
```

Remind, that paths starting with `..`, or `.` are *not* resolved against the include-path, but only against the current work directory.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in the second case, you're specifying a path, but in the first case it uses your includes path.  Perhaps rather than explicitly specifying .. in the second case, you  case modify your include path.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and I'll look into it this morning, but I've never had a problem with using "./" or "../" before inside a require_once() statement, and never once had to use the set_include_path() function to correct any issues like this before. Thanks again!

Comment: IMHO, set include path is not of significance when you are directly including a file as @kim is doing, do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It could be if someone did a chdir or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but it is still relevant.

In my experience, the ["open_basedir" directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) is most likely to cause this issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once('fruit.php');
```

This searches for fruit.php in the same directory as widget.php is in, no matter what the current working directory is.

```
require_once('../fruit.php');
```

This searches for fruit.php in a directory above the **current** directory, not in the directory above the one widget.php is in.

Comment: No, thats wrong. `fruit.php` tries to resolve the path using the `include_path` (remind, that the current work directory `.` is usually part of it) and `../fruit.php` tries to resolve it _only_ using the current work directory.

Comment: Additional: Calling `fruit.php` does not mean, that the current work directory points to the directory, where `fruit.php` is: `php some/directory/fruit.php`. Or it got changed using `chwd()`