# Cron Job command not working

Tags: php, linux, cron, cpanel, cronexpression

I have a simple script in my server and I need a cron job to make it run every minute. I am using cPanel to set it. What should I enter in the cron job "command" field? I am newbie with cron job commands, I have tried many different options:

```
/home/enkaizen/public_html/soporte/wp-content/scripts/index.php

/usr/local/bin/php /home/enkaizene/public_html/soporte/wp-content/scripts/index.php

/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/enkaizene/public_html/soporte/wp-content/scripts/index.php

/usr/bin/php /home/enkaizene/public_html/soporte/wp-content/scripts/index.php

/usr/bin/php -q /home/enkaizene/public_html/soporte/wp-content/scripts/index.php
```

But none seem to be working. I know my script is correct because when I run it manually it does what it is suppose to do.

For in case it helps, my host is https://www.frenzysolutions.com

Any ideas what can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To run php from cron try the f flag

`php -f /home/enkaizen/public_html/soporte/wp-content/scripts/index.php`

It is best practice to use the full path to the executable when using cron. Unfortunately this is distribution/os dependent but it is probably either `/usr/bin/php` or `/usr/local/bin/php`

Comment: I tried that one "php -f /home/..." but it is not working. 
Other programmers have used:  

`/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/enkaizen/public_html/app/Console/cake.php revenue -app /home/enkaizen/public_html/app` 
also 
`/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/enkaizen/public_html/app/Console/cake.php revenuemail -app /home/enkaizen/public_html/app   `

It tried to make mine similar to theirs but no luck. Please help

Comment: Actually it works with your solution! . what happens is that I am using require_once scripts. When I take those off, it works, otherwise it does not. But I need those require_once files. Any idea how I can fix this? Thank you

Comment: Are the require_once statements absolute paths like: `<?php require_once('/var/www/public_html/config.php'); ?> ` or dynamic like `<?php
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/config.php');
?> ` ?

Comment: They are absolute. I am "requiring_once" 2 files in a sub-directory and 1 files in a directory 2 levels down "/../..".

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php indicates you may have better luck if you switch them to dynamic.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050192/running-a-php-file-from-crontab-that-includes-require-once

Comment: The file I want to run with the cron job is `public_html/soporte/wp-content/scripts/index.php`, how can I include this file `public_html/soporte/wp-header.php`? .... `require_once (__FILE__ .'/../../wp-blog-header.php');` is not doing it. Please advise

Comment: Try `require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../wp-blog-header.php');`

Comment: No luck. I know the cron is hitting because if I remove the require_once and place a little function to write a log, it does it. I don't know what else to try... any other thought you might have?

Comment: I just found out that the problem is when I require_once a wordpress file "wp-header.php", not when I require_once any other non wordpress file. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Probably, I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any error with "php -q" command ?

Also you can use curl command instead of php -q to execute your scripts through command line.