# Errors with require_once in php

Tags: php

I don't know why when i add a require_once function in my code, it can not run, always show that failed to open stream.

```
<?php  require_once("../../../../cadpro_vs2/include/admin/ad_nav.php") ?>
```

Any mistake on syntax or something, please help!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the exact error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are in the wrong work directory. Its a bad idea to rely on it (except you explictly want to access it) anyway. Use

```
require __DIR__ . '/../fruit.php';
```

or with pre-5.3

```
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../fruit.php';
```

Remind, that paths starting with .., or . are not resolved against the include-path, but only against the current work directory.

To get more elaborated idea, visit [require_once](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php)

Source: [Require_once PHP Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649104/require-once-php-error)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
require_once(__ROOT__.'/cadpro_vs2/include/admin/ad_nav.php');
```

if this code cant help you, check your path.
maybe file not exist